# Malformed error while generating token for outlook and then exchanging with graphapi

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-rest-api, azure-service-principal

When I try to generate access token for a user in Outlook and then Exchanging Access Token for graph Api it failed with malformed error.

To generate access token, I passed these values

[image]

Complete error is:

```
   {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
        "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: ba68002d-e58b-4d65-9e61-6e5ca2845500\r\nCorrelation ID: 03ee058c-38cb-407d-9b88-f51b7c992464\r\nTimestamp: 2022-10-19 15:05:17Z",
        "error_codes": [
        9002313
        ],
        "timestamp": "2022-10-19 15:05:17Z",
        "trace_id": "ba68002d-e58b-4d65-9e61-6e5ca2845500",
        "correlation_id": "03ee058c-38cb-407d-9b88-f51b7c992464",
        "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
        }
```

I granted these permissions with consented

[image]

What does the error mean grant type is wrong, or endpoint is not valid? Or Am I missing any permissions? Please help me in resolving the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the **`code`** parameter value is not valid. Make sure to generate the **`code`** value by using the below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=e626f30a-80ea-*********-******
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=user.read openid profile offline_access email mail.read 
&state=12345
```

[image]

***I am able to generate access token successfully when I passed the above `code` value like below:***

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token 

client_id:clientid
client_secret:clientsecret
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
scope:email Mail.Read offline_access openid profile User.Read
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
```

[image]